# C# Terminate a Class Library which implements a DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, kill, class-library

I am using a class library to simulate and process data and return results via triggered events.

```
DataProcessor _dataProcessor
```

In it I am using a DispatcherTimer to simulate data and raise events when simulated data is available and ready to be pushed to GUI.

Was wondering how best to kill the _dataProcessor?

My experience is that setting

```
_dataProcessor = null;
```

does not kill the DispatcherTimer. The events are still raised and still passed up to the GUI.

Do I have to stop/null out the DispatcherTimer before the GAC will dispose of the class library?

Thank you for any guidance as I'm not sure the best way to approach this task in general, yet alone terminating the instance of the class library on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DispatcherTimer keeps itself alive while it is enabled, even if you don't keep a reference to it.  Rather important, nobody expects a timer to stop raising events unless asking it explicitly to Stop().  It does so by adding a reference to itself into a private List<> kept by the Dispatcher.  And removing that reference in Stop().

Which in turn ensures that your DataProcessor will not get garbage collected if it has a non-static Tick event handler.  Setting the reference you keep to null has no effect, the references kept by Dispatcher and the event delegate keep the object alive.

You'll need to add a method to DataProcessor that stops the timer.

Comment: This has been my experience and answers my question. I have implemented such a method to stop the timer and it seems to do the trick. I suspect my downfall is the DispatcherTimer so I will investigate other timer options.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataProcessor` class should implement the `IDisposable` interface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Then you could call DispatchTimer.Stop() when you want to kill your `DataProcessor` class.

```
public class DataProcessor : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false; 
    DispatchTimer timer;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if(timer != null)
                   timer.Stop();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~DataProcessor()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Use it:

```
using(DataProcessor process = new DataProcessor)
{
     //etc...
} //stop timer
```

Comment: Does it make sense to call `GC.SuppressFinalize` if you don't have a finalizer?.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find `DispatcherTimer` in standard .NET class list, so I assume it's your own class. If this is the case then standard pattern is for your `DispatcherTimer` class to implement `IDisposable`, and then call `_dataProcessor.Dispose()` when you no longer need it, or dispose it by means of `using` keyword

Comment: No, `DispatchTimer` is a WPF class, it is part of the .Net framework though, and it does not implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

galets and EkoostikMartin have answered the question already. Let me explain the `using`-statement in more detail. This same keyword is used in two different statements in c#. I won't discuss `using <namesapce>;` here. The other can be used in methods. Assuming that `DispatchTimer` implements `IDisposable`:

```
using (var timer = new DispatchTimer()) {
    timer.Start();
    // ... do something here.
}
```

does the same as

```
{
   var timer = new DispatchTimer();
   try {
       timer.Start();
       // ... do something here.
   } finally {
       if (timer != null) {
           ((IDisposable)timer).Dispose();
       }
   }
}
```

It gives you a safe way to close or terminate something you have opened or started. Dispose will even be called if an exception occurs within the using block or if the using block if left by `return` for example.

---

#### UPDATE

As EkoostikMartin sais in his comment, `DispatchTimer` does not implement `IDisposable` but you can easily create a disposable version of it

```
public class DisposableDispatchTimer : DispatchTimer, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: `DispatchTimer` is a WPF class though, and it doesn't implement IDisposable. This makes your example confusing.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: OK, you are right. I found `DispatchTimer` in  `System.Windows.Threading`. It does in fact not implement `IDisposable` as you said. But since the class is not sealed, you could easily derive your own class from it and implement `IDisposable`.